# jQuery - Store conditions in a string and execute them later

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating my own templating engine which is used to render HTML.

Below, you have a template which will be rendered using my template engine:

```
{{TMPL:Import=../../../../Data/Templates/Ribbon/tabs.tmpl; Name=Tabs}}
<div id="{{Id}}" class="ribbon">

    <!-- All the different tabs are being rendered here. -->
    {{Render:Tabs; Value="Tabs"}}
</div>
```

Now, I was think about a technique on how I could make some sections render if a condition matches.

I tought to change my template as following:

```
{{TMPL:Import=../../../../Data/Templates/Ribbon/tabs.tmpl; Name=Tabs}}
{{If: "{{Id}}" != "Undefined"}}
    <div id="{{Id}}" class="ribbon">

        <!-- All the different tabs are being rendered here. -->
        {{Render:Tabs; Value="Tabs"}}
    </div>
{{EndIf}}
```

In human language, that would be, id the parameter "Id", which is passed by my template engine, is not "undefined, that I would render the div element.

But now I want to know how I can execute this condition.

Through the usage of regexes and replacements, the final condition will look like this:

```
"Undefined" != "Undefined"
```

But this is stored a a simple text value.

Is there a way in jQuery / Javascript, on how I can execute the condition stored in the string?

Kind regards,

Comment: you lost me at "I'm creating my own templating engine" :) unless ofc it's for teaching purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval('"Undefined" != "Undefined"')

Comment: Thanks, I just need to pass my FULL if statement in their, I've just tested it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Be careful with eval though, @Complexity. If user input makes its way into your expression, this might introduce cross site scripting issues. You're welcome, but no need to thank me for an answer, however accepting it would be nice if it works ;-)

Comment: So, I've accepted it. Thanks again for your answer. User input would never make it's way into the eval function. It's a templating framework and the templates are stored in the website's directory and will only be modified by an administrator of the website.